# detox --debug-synchronization not working

Tags: react-native, jestjs, detox

I am trying to figure out what parts of my React Native app are causing Detox to wait unnecessarily long [as instructed in the documentation](https://github.com/wix/Detox/blob/master/docs/Troubleshooting.Synchronization.md#identifying-which-synchronization-mechanism-causes-us-to-wait-too-much). However, when I run:

```
detox test --debug-synchronization 20
```

I get no additional output, only the regular Jest output. I know for a fact that there are network requests slower than that, `setTimeout`'s of 400 ms and animations which are slowing Detox down, but it doesn't output them.

What could be causing the output not to work?

Comment: Is this for iOS? If so, try the more advanced method. It will give you better results.

Answer (score 0):

This feature had a bug before and they just fixed it in this release: [18.18.0](https://github.com/wix/Detox/releases/tag/18.18.0)

You may consider this apprach as well

```
await device.disableSynchronization();
```

put this line before interacting with the animated element
and then you can enable the synchorization again

```
await device.enableSynchronization();
```